# Magento, add attribute to several groups on same attribute set

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Is that possible? I tried doing it using the admin GUI. When I add the attribute it dissapears from the available attributes, as usual, but if I move it inside the groups on the attribute set there is no option of "copying" or alike.

I realized of this issue as programmatically we are importing products, categories and attributes. On the language attributes we have for example *german*. It is used in several places, for manual language, for titles, descriptions, etc. We didn't knew about it and just realized when detected that the attribute is only found on the last created group where it was placed.

If it is not possible then how do we solve this issue? Should we create several different attributes to be used on different groups inside an attribute set? Maybe **german_manual**, **geman_language** or something similar? Or there is already a solution for this and we do now know it?

Hope I have clearly described my question, is somewhat complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Attribute Set* is virtual box for attributes (we can consider attributes as physical properties). *Groups* inside one *Attribute Set* is just more virtual boxes to split one big "box" (*Attribute Set*), they are created to simplify attribute management, divide *Attribute Set* on logical containers.

Now as I understood from your question, you want 1 attribute to be assigned to 2 different Groups inside 1 *Attribute Set*. It's the same that put 1 stone into 2 boxes...

Comment: Understood. Then how I can do it?

Comment: Your attributes should represent 1 property of the product you have. I can't give you direct advises as to what attributes should you create, because I don't know anything about your products, but if you need 1 attribute to belong to few Groups, it's sign that there's an ambiguity going on with that attribute. You need to split it in the way that each attribute represents only 1 property.

Comment: Just where talking about with our manager and discussing about. You are right, we should create several different attributes and assign them to different groups as needed. Run out of upvotes for today but at least I will accept the answer.